# FlowableEmitter doesn't signal error when onNext got null

Tags: rx-java

I expected that FlowableEmitter would signal error when I set null to onNext's parameter 
since *What's different in 2.0* said

> RxJava 2.x no longer accepts null values
>   and the following will yield NullPointerException immediately
>   or as a signal to downstream:

However, it seems to call onComplete.
Is this a right action?

```
Flowable.create(emitter -> {
  emitter.onNext(1);
  emitter.onNext(null);
  emitter.onNext(3);
  emitter.onComplete();
}, BackpressureMode.BUFFER).subscribe(
    System.out::println,
    e -> e.printStackTrace(), 
    () -> System.out.println("done"));
```

The result is

1
   done

I tried on RxJava 2.0.0-RC2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with `Flowable.create()` and you should get a `NullPointerException` via `onError`. I'll post [a fix for this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/4583) (and similar other places) and tomorrow you can continue with RC3.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I'm sure that this is a bug and what I have to do.

Comment: I tried on RxJava 2.0.0-RC3. It fixed and I got `NullPointerException` as I expected.